Probability distribution for the time needed to first exceed a certain number?
I have a 4 State Markov Chain with state space $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4\}$ and a transition matrix $P$ where:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & p_{14} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & p_{24} \\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34} \\
p_{41} & p_{42} & p_{43} & p_{44}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Each state has an associated score value:
$$f(s_i) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } i = 1 \\
0 & \text{if } i = 2 \\
1 & \text{if } i = 3 \\
2 & \text{if } i = 4
\end{cases}$$
Suppose I currently start in State 2 with Score=0 . How do I find out a probability distribution for the time needed to first reach/exceed a score=10?
For limited problems, I can simulate this:

But how can I make a probability distribution for this problem? For example, suppose I wanted to find out how much time is needed to first reach/exceed a score of 999,999 ? It would take so long to simulate even one iteration.
Is there a way to mathematically define a probability distribution for these kinds of problems?
